# Timezone two hours behind

Tags: python

The server is outputting the current local time 2 hours behind the actual time. I need to add 2 hours, so the log produces the correct time. My attempts have not produced the desired result. Any ideas where I went wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import datetime

vcenter_timestamp = '2023-06-06T15:55:53.232524391Z'[:19]

server_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
server_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(vcenter_timestamp, server_format)
local_tz = ZoneInfo('Europe/Rome')
local_dt = server_dt.astimezone(local_tz)
output_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
dt_rome = (local_dt.strftime(output_format))

print(dt_rome)
```

Current Output

```
2023-06-06 15:55:53
```

Desired Output

```
2023-06-06 17:55:53
```

Comment: The input actually contains the correct time with the timezone (`"Z"`) included. You are then ignoring the timezone and getting wrong time in the end.

Comment: @zvone It's the server time in the input, which for some reason is 2 hours behind the local time. It needs to output 17 rather than 15.

Comment: `2023-06-06T15:55:53.232524391Z` is 17:55 in Rome, i.e. that is `2023-06-06T17:55:53.232524391+02:00`. It is the same time in a different timezone. You need to parse it with the timezone and then convert the timezone. If you parse it without the timezone, then you cannot convert correctly, because information is lost.

Comment: @zvone I'm not sure if I follow. Mind putting that into an answer to the question?

Comment: @zvone is quite right.  The server is giving you the time in UTC (or GMT), probably because it doesn't know what time zone YOU are in.  You just need to convert that to your localtime.

Answer (score 4):

The timestamp you are receiving, "2023-06-06T15:55:53.232524391Z" is for the UTC timezone, that's what the bare Z (historically 'Zulu time') at the end indicates.  That's why it's 2 hours earlier than your local Rome time.   For more on the date format, read  [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

If you are using a modern python you can parse this directly into a timezone-aware datetime and then convert it to your local zone:

```
    import datetime
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
    timestamp = '2023-06-06T15:55:53.232524391Z'
    utc_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp)
    rome_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Rome'))
    print('utc  ', utc_dt)
    print('rome ', rome_dt)
```

output:

```
    utc   2023-06-06 15:55:53.232524+00:00
    rome  2023-06-06 17:55:53.232524+02:00
```

If you are on an old python, or they didn't have the Z at the end but you knew it was a UTC timestamp you could parse it with plain old strptime() and attach the UTC timezone to the tz-naive datetime object and then convert it.:

```
    import datetime
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
    timestamp = '2023-06-06T15:55:53.232524391'[:19]
    naive_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    utc_dt = naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.UTC)
    rome_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo('Europe/Rome'))
    print('naive', naive_dt)
    print('utc  ', utc_dt)
    print('rome ', rome_dt)
```

note that the UTC tzinfo in older pythons is available at datetime.timezone.utc, and in recent ones it's datetime.UTC

output:

```
    naive 2023-06-06 15:55:53
    utc   2023-06-06 15:55:53+00:00
    rome  2023-06-06 17:55:53+02:00
```

a key thing to remember is that datetime.replace(tzinfo=[tz]) is how you add or replace a timezone (without changing the hours!)

datetime.astimezone([tz]) converts the time to the new timezone.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. While it works quite well, I was wondering if there could be a more permanent fix that takes into account daylight savings changes. Otherwise, I'd have to modify the scripts twice a year.

Comment: :) that's what the last paragraph is about.  If you know what the timezone of vcenter_timestamp is, use replace(tzinfo=<tz>) to put that timezone object on it, then convert it to whatever timezone you want to work in with .astimezone(<tz>).    it all depends on just what is really happening with that vcenter_timestamp data.   is it an accurate time from a different zone or is it a mis-set clock in the right timezone?  good luck

Comment: Yeah, they're both in Rome. I don't understand why it outputs the time 2 hours behind though...

Comment: OH!  the Z on the end means you are getting a UTC (aka Zulu time) timestamp.  it has a timezone on it - UTC.  i'll update my answer

Comment: Think about putting the correct answer (the one that takes into account the timezone data present in the string) _first_ -- I downvoted this on account of not seeing it and had to go back and retract. We don't really have a strong tradition of edit markers here: because a Stack Overflow question and answer are written mostly for future readers, it's important to make edits read smoothly to people seeing the question for the first time than to make people who already saw it in the past understand the edit history (when there's an edit-history link right there at the bottom of the question).

Comment: thanks charles, i'll edit it into a tighter answer.

Comment: The datetime.UTC doesnt work for me (utc_dt = naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.UTC)). I get an AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'UTC'

Comment: My other issues is that I can't have that +02:00. I need the actual time converted to the local time, so instead of 15:00+02:00, I need to have 17:00. I see the rome printout does that, but until I get that UTC fixed, I can't run the code.

Comment: `datetime.UTC` requires Python 3.11. On earlier versions `datetime.timezone.UTC` will work.

Comment: OverflowStack - the "+02:00" is not some sort of time-math, it's a notation of the timezone (short for "UTC + 2 hours").  so the time is the local time you would see on a clock in that timezone.   notice that the output in my example IS 17:00.

Also, @slothrop - good to note, i'll edit the answer to add that.

Comment: To exclude the "+02:00" from the printed output, you can use .strftime with an appropriate format string. For example, `print('rome ', rome_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` will print `rome 2023-06-06 17:55:53`)